# Refining my SQL query to only show people who appear two or more times on a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write an SQL query that "Find bookings for a guest who has booked one room several times on different dates."

I have a postgress database with a `guests` table

```
hotel7=# SELECT * FROM guest;
 guest_id |  name   |    phone     |     email     
----------+---------+--------------+---------------
    1 | kat     | 111-111-1111 | kat@g.com
    2 | andy    | 222-222-2222 | andy@g.com
    3 | theda   | 333-333-3333 | theda@g.com
    4 | forrest | 444-444-4444 | forrest@g.com
    5 | trent   | 555-555-5555 | trent@g.com
    6 | cyle    | 666-666-6666 | cyle@g.com
(6 rows)
```

and a `reservation` table that lists all the reservations that have been made.

```
hotel7=# SELECT * FROM reservation;
 res_id | guest_id |  check_in  | check_out  
--------+----------+------------+------------
  1 |        1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-03
  2 |        1 | 2017-12-05 | 2017-12-07
  3 |        2 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-02
  4 |        2 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10
  5 |        3 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10
  6 |        4 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-30
  7 |        5 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-22
(7 rows)
```

There are a few other tables that don't seem necessary to the question.

So far the closest I have gotten is

```
hotel7=# SELECT g.name FROM guest AS g  
LEFT JOIN reservation AS r
ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id;
  name   
---------
 kat
 kat
 andy
 andy
 theda
 forrest
 trent
 cyle
(8 rows)
```

All I need is to only show the people who appear twice on the list.

Comment: Try adding Having COUNT(*) > 1 to your select

Comment: "who has booked one room several times": I don't see a room in the tables you are showing, so there must be another table with this information. We need this in order to determine whether two bookings refer to the same room.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.guest_id, A.name
FROM
guest A
LEFT JOIN
reservation B
ON A.guest_id = B.guest_id
GROUP BY A.guest_id, A.name
HAVING COUNT(res_id) > 1;
```

For every `guest_id`, it will calculate how many (non-NULL)`res_id` are present in the table `reservation` and with `HAVING` condition, you can make sure that you get only those with more than one reservations.

If there were a field like `booking_date`, you could have used `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT booking_date) > 1` in the query to see if the booking was made on two different dates by the same person, but you only have check-in and check-out dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

SELECT g.name FROM guest AS g
LEFT JOIN reservation AS r
ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
having COUNT(guest_id)>1;